# Telegram app freezes on Aquaris M10

Tags: ubuntu-touch, crash, aquaris, m10, telegram

I can't seem to get a lot of use out of the telegram app on the Aquaris M10 tablet.
I start the app, choose the country, enter the phone number, and log in with the code texted to me. OK so far.

I then go to add a contact, and choose to manually enter the details.
As soon as I click to manually enter, the app screen goes white, and freezes without recovery.
When I close and re-open the app, I have to enter the country, phone number, and texted code again.

Has anyone else experienced this? Or, more importantly, does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: I just tried the same mettod as you listed and my telegram crashed out. I had to enter select my country and number again. Good find, please log it in launchpad and post the link here. Then others can click on the link and tag it as affecting them too. I will. Until this is resolved can you add contacts to your address book and then select contacts from there, rather than adding them manually?

Comment: Thanks Phil. Is there anywhere I can find out more about logging in launchpad? Personally, I don't even know what that is.

Comment: Ha, never mind. A little google, and I figured out how to use launchpad. I logged the bug in the Telegram app group, and here is the link. https://bugs.launchpad.net/telegram-app/+bug/1631192

Comment: Thanks, I have marked it as affecting me too. Hopefully more people will mark it and the developers will fix it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like I can add from the contacts either. If I try, I am led to my contacts list, where I can select which contacts I want. But, after selecting contacts, there is no way to accept the selection. I can only go "back"